# c# TcpListener кастомный веб сервер

Tags: c#, post, веб-сервер, tcplistener

Делаю кастомный веб сервер с помощью TcpListener, под уже готовый клиент ..
Клиент выполняется на моём компьютере там же где я делаю сервер ( исходного кода клиента у меня нет) и клиент всегда обращается к Localhost. По этому сертификат само-подписанный.

Почему не использую HttpListener или ASP.NET или ещё что-то готовое(ака не делай велосипед .. ) - потому-что используется своя библиотека для сжатия данных(хоть там и указывается что " Accept-Encoding: deflate "), и она не совпадает с тем что делают все остальные, нужно делать именно с ней, она у меня есть ( исходного кода нету) с ней всё работает. Ну и HttpListener лично у меня не хочет получать сертификат, т.е. я свой сертификат уже по применял везде где только возможно и при запуске сервера при его использовании выдаёт ошибку о сертификате .. по этому остановился на TcpListener.

Работает с HTTPS протоколом используя само-подписанный сертификат с паролем.
Нормально принимает GET запросы и отправляет файлы если нужно, но возникает проблема, когда от клиента приходит POST запрос с данными.

**Итак вот в чём проблема:**
Приходит заголовок HTTPS

```
POST https://127.0.0.1/SomeUrl HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Accept-Encoding: deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 45
Content-Encoding: deflate
```

Дальше должен был бы идти контент который нужно распаковать ( бо там deflate encoding ) но его нету, и SslStream пустой... (SslStream - поток для работы с SSL .. ) при этом клиент 100% отправил данные , и уверенно ждёт что я ему уже дам ответ .. ( все запросы проверял используя программу Fiddler Everywhere )

**Теперь кусок кода отвечающий за сервер:**

```
private static Semaphore clientsFreeRequests = new Semaphore(40, 40);
private static TcpListener listener;
private static X509Certificate certificate;
public static void Init()
{
    certificate = new X509Certificate("Servercert.pfx","1234");
    listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),443);
    listener.Start();
    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessRequests)) { IsBackground = true};
    thread.Start();
}
private static void ProcessRequests()
{
    while (true)
    {
        clientsFreeRequests.WaitOne();
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(AcceptSocket), null);
    }
}

private static void AcceptSocket(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult);
    if (client.Connected)
    {
        RemoteCertificateValidationCallback ValidateClientCertificate = (q1, q2, q3, q4) => true;
        SslStream stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateClientCertificate),
            null);
        stream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, false, false);
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            
            while (client.Connected && client.Available > 0)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[client.Available];
                stream.Read(buffer);
                string tmp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                Request request = new Request(tmp);
                // Request - это самописный класс который просто разбирает запрос на составляющие в свои параметры для простоты работы..
                // тут дальше идёт работа с запросом и отправка ответа через stream (SslStream)
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Соединение всегда keep-alive пока клиент не решит отключится, по этому не выполняю close а просто жду следующих данных, да тут можно поменять чтобы не шло по цикло постоянно, а выполнило stream.Read - этот вызов ждёт пока не придут данные .. но тогда надо подгадывать с размером буфера и получать рваные данные, а так у меня буфер всегда размером под пришедшие данные.
        }
        stream.Close();
    }

    clientsFreeRequests.Release();
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126750/discussion-on-question-by-getyoufun-c-tcplistener---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем лично в моём коде достаточно сделать вот такое изменение -

```
private static void AcceptSocket(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    *****
    byte[] buffer = new byte[client.Available];
    stream.Read(buffer);
    string tmp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    Request request = new Request(tmp);
    // при условии что пришел POST запрос - нужно просто после заголовка читать ровно столько данных сколько укажет header - Content-Length с помощью stream.Read(buffer,0,contentLength);
                
    ****
}
```